# Chrome Extension - Unable to get 'delayed' response from eventPage.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I just started a chrome extension yesterday so I am fairly new, please excuse my noob questions.

I have a popup.js which displays contents in popup.html - So popup.js is simple

popup.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function (tab) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
            tab: tab
        }, function (response) {

            document.getElementById("lockDiv").hidden = false;
            document.getElementById("loadingDiv").hidden = true;

        });       

    });
});
```

It gets the selected tab, sends a message (with tab) to event page which is the following

eventPage.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (tab) { 

    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        setInterval(function () {
           // Do something after 5 seconds          
        }, 5000);
    });   
});
```

Now it works (sort of) but as soon as popup.js runs, there is no delay for 5 seconds before this executes

```
        document.getElementById("lockDiv").hidden = false;
        document.getElementById("loadingDiv").hidden = true;
```

The above executes without waiting for the response from eventPage.js

How can I make this to wait for a response and let the operation in evenPage.js to finish before showing executed the above code?

Comment: Add `return true` before exiting onMessage listener. And use `sendResponse` in onMessage listener.

Answer (score -1):

Having read [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage#addListener_syntax) for onMessage - *(it should work the same as chrum extension as mozilla web extensions are based on Chrum)* -conentrating on the part about "To send a response asynchronously" - you can do the following (apparently)

eventPage.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (tab) { 
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setInterval(function () {
            // Do something after 5 seconds          
            resolve(resultYouWantToReturn)
            }, 5000);
        });
    });   
});
```

popup.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    tab: tab
}, function (response) {
    response.then(resultFromListener => {
        // resultFromListener is the value resolved (resultYouWantToReturn) above
        document.getElementById("lockDiv").hidden = false;
        document.getElementById("loadingDiv").hidden = true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Chrome API doesn't work with Promises. The OP needs `return true` in onMessage as explained in the documentation.

Comment: interesting - MDN documentation doesn't mention that inconsistency. Surprising since Mozilla is basing it's API on Chrome

Comment: Promises work with `browser` namespace, which is WebExtension API, not Chrome API.

Comment: question is tagged google-chrome-extension - I assumed from the tag info that it was indeed about what is now called a Web Extension